# Does RDS proxy support automatic or transparent read/write splitting

Tags: amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

Can we do  automatic or transparent read/write splitting using amazon RDS proxy or we  need to explicitly give reader and writer point to split that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, RDS proxy does not support read write split by own.
Here is the link for your help :
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/